# Dynamic expression evaluator at runtime

Tags: java, algorithm, groovy

I have an app that I wanted to customize using some sort of expression evaluator.
I wanted to change certain parts of the app without recompiling my code.
I am thinking of using groovy expression.

Say for example, I have a feature that can be enabled/disabled by supplying expression:

In this case, this feature will be enabled

```
Example 1:
EXPRESSION : status = part-time || status = hourly
INPUT: status = part-time
```

In this case, this feature will be disabled

```
Example 2:
EXPRESSION : status = part-time || status = hourly
INPUT: status = permanent
```

Users are required to enter an expression and an Input.  Expression should evaluate to a boolean expression

They can also change the expression and the program will pick up this by some evaluation.
These expressions by the way are documented and is exposed by me to the user of my application

```
Example 3:
EXPRESSION : salary > 10000
INPUT: salary = 7000
```

I have seen a program before that does this and they say that they uses groovy under the hood.
But I cannot get my head wrap around the concept.

Can somebody please give me an idea?

Comment: What are you specifically trying to do? What's the problem you're trying to solve? If it's just enabling or disabling a feature a boolean variable does that for you, so it's difficult to see what the issue is here.

Comment: Hi Mate, As I have mentioned..I wanted my program to have the capability to change its behavior by passing expressions.. this is so there is no need  for me to recompile my code.  The idea is that anybody can extend my code without changing the underlying program and buy just using expression exposed.

Comment: I don't get the close vote in my question.  I am asking for guidance so I cannot post any code.  Why do I receive a close vote.  It doesn't makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the usual call of groovy script:

```
import groovy.lang.Binding;
import groovy.lang.Script;
import groovy.lang.GroovyShell;

Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.setProperty("status", "part-time");
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);
Script script = shell.parse(" status == 'part-time' || status == 'hourly' ");
Object result = script.run();
```

after run the binding will be populated with new values of the variables.

you can cache the parsed script (or class of the parsed script) because parsing/compiling is expensive process.

as alternative - the easiest script evaluation:

```
Object result = groovy.util.Eval.me("status", "part-time", 
    " status == 'part-time' || status == 'hourly' ");
```

Comment: Ohh so thats how it is... how do you parse those expression that are having a .(dot). Say for example instead of status... it will be employee.status? I am having compilation problem when evaluating in groovy

Comment: you can consider groovy as a dynamically compiled java. you just have to pass `employee` variable into your script and script will ve able to access all properties and methods of this object.

Comment: but employee isn't an object.. it is just a label or something... I am getting groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: employee for class: Script1

Comment: Is there a way to skip the (dot)... expression could be label.name or sample.data?

Comment: look, in the code that i've provided in the answer the line `binding.setProperty("status", "part-time")` defines the variable named `status` that refers java `String` object with value `part-time`. in the groovy script you can access java String method `toUpperCase()` like this: `status.toUpperCase()`, and this expression will return `PART-TIME`

Answer (score 3):

Alternative approach using `evaluate`. Your variables are defined in binding, `evaluate` contains the expression:

```
// setup binding
def emp = [status:'permanent', name:'Hugo']
def binding = new Binding()
binding.status = 'permanent'
binding.status2 = 'part-time'
binding.salary = 7000
binding.employee = emp
println binding.variables

// evaluate the script
def ret = new GroovyShell(binding).evaluate("status == 'part-time' || status == 'hourly'")
println ret

ret = new GroovyShell(binding).evaluate("status2 == 'part-time' || status2 == 'hourly'")
println ret

ret = new GroovyShell(binding).evaluate("salary > 10000")
println ret

ret = new GroovyShell(binding).evaluate("employee.status == 'permanent' || employee.status == 'hourly'")
println ret
```

returns

```
[status:permanent, status2:part-time, salary:7000, employee:[status:permanent, name:Hugo]]
false
true
false
true
```

Comment: Ohh so thats how it is... how do you parse those expression that are having a .(dot).  Say for example instead of status... it will be employee.status? I am having compilation problem when evaluating in groovy

Comment: @MarkEstrada added an example using bining of a hash map